# Sharepoint designer workflow - send an email to dynamic email address

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer

I am creating a workflow in sharepoint designer 2013 that will send out a standard email to a user specified email address. The email address would be specified at the beginning of the workflow by the user on a sharepoint site and not in sharepoint designer. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Email action you can use variable from your list